# SVN - reject, change and revert to previous version

Tags: svn, csv

We have an SVN repository with a few users. One of the users accidently deleted a directory and checked in the change.

I could just check out an older version of the directly and recheck it back in but I do not want to lose the version information on the directory in the SVN.

How do I reject the change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using TortoiseSVN, it implements a "rollback" feature.  Here's the documentation: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html.

If you use another client, you can still do this manually.  You may want to check out this link: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.resurrect

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the command line, the typical method is to do a "reverse merge".  For example, if version 125 was the checkin that deleted the directory, then you would execute a command like this: `svn merge -r 125:124`. This will cause subversion to pull the directory out of the history and drop it into the working copy.  Once you verify that everything is correct, you can issue a commit and put the directory back into subversion.